# Laravel - Maatwebsite import on failure redirects to Login Page

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

In my Laravel-5.8, I am importing from Excel into database using Maatwebsites-3.1:

```
public function importGrade(Request $request){
    $request->validate([
        'file' => 'required|max:10000|mimes:xlsx,xls',
    ]);
  $path1 = $request->file('file')->store('import'); 
  $path=storage_path('app').'/'.$path1;  
  
        $import = new GradeLevelsImport;
        $import->import($path); 
        if ($import->failures()->isNotEmpty()) {
            Session::flash('error', $import->failures()); 
            return redirect()->route('hr.grades.index');   
        }            
         
        Session::flash('success', 'Grade Records Imported Successfully');
        return redirect()->route('hr.grades.index');              
}
```

On failure, it redirects me to the Login Page. The problem is coming from here:

```
        if ($import->failures()->isNotEmpty()) {
            Session::flash('error', $import->failures()); 
            return redirect()->route('hr.grades.index');   
        }
```

Even when I changed it to:

```
        if ($import->failures()->isNotEmpty()) {
            Session::flash('error', $import->failures()); 
            return back();     
        }
```

And even when I used:

```
return back()->withFailures($import->failures());
```

The problem still persists.

How do I get it resolved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html#handling-validation-errors

You should catch an error with try-catch.

```
try {
    $import->import($path);
} catch(\Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\ValidationException $e) {
    Session::flash('error', $e->failures()); 
    return redirect()->route('hr.grades.index');   
}
```